# KML loads entire time span together

Tags: kml, google-earth

In a kml is it possible to to have "region + networkLink + onRegion" type effect over timeSpan, i.e. load the time span only when desired (something like ''onTime'')? Currently my kml loads the entire time span on opening in GE. Since I have data spread over a large time period, it becomes very slow. Can somebody provide me some suggestions or alternatives to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this query, and am posting the answer in case somebody needs it in future.

Using LookAt/ camera element in the base kml is the solution to avoid loading all times Steps together.
Something like:

```
 <LookAt>
      <latitude>0</latitude>
      <longitude>20</longitude>
      <altitude>50000</altitude>
      <range>10000000</range>
      <tilt>10</tilt>
      <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
      <TimeSpan>
          <begin>2011-02-01T12:00:00Z</begin>
  <end>2011-02-02T12:00:00Z</end>   
      </TimeSpan>
</LookAt>
```

Comment: LookAt and Camera can only have gx:TimeSpan or gx:TimeStamp elements which are Google Earth KML extensions. See [KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#abstractview)